# web socket with multiple streams, will all code run if it takes longer than the interval period to execute?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, stream

I set up a web socket in Python receiving multiple data streams. It receives data every minute from multiple streams.

```
stream_urls = [stream_url1, stream_url2, etc.]
async with websockets.connect(stream_urls,ping_timeout=None) as sock:
    while True:
        res = await asyncio.wait_for(sock.recv(),timeout=reply_timeout)
        res = json.loads(res)
        # code runs here on data in res
```

Each time data is received code is executed, but what happens if on at least one occasion this code for example takes longer than a minute to run?

E.g. data is received for data from stream_url1 at time 14:05 and the code takes 70 seconds to run (or even multiple received streams in total take longer than 60 seconds), then for that minute (14:05) will the code run for stream_url2, i.e. does it all queue up until everything is executed, or will it just skip to the 14:06 data and the code is not run for the 14:05 stream_url2 data?

By now I am guessing that I need to execute this code in a thread so it carries out all the expected code for each stream_url at each minute, but in my application I original supposed this might not be necessary as it only takes longer than a minute very occasionally so there will not be a great backlog.

It would be great if someone could clarify the behaviour of using a socket like this and whether it will actually execute all the code at each minute for all streams in the event the code takes a longer than a minute to run.